# Using an array of strings as a function parameter in a function that builds another array

Tags: swift, ffmpeg

I start with an empty array:

```
var ffmpegFilters = [String]()
```

I have a button that should start an ffmpeg process when I click it:

```
@IBAction func startConversionClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    //buildFfmpegString()
    ffmpegConvert(inputPath: inputFilePath, filters: ffmpegFilters, outputPath: "outputFilePath")
}
```

The function with the process looks like this:

```
func ffmpegConvert(inputPath: String, filters: String, outputPath: String) {
    guard let launchPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ffmpeg", ofType: "") else { return }
    do {
        let convertTask: Process = Process()
        convertTask.launchPath = launchPath
        convertTask.arguments = [
            "-i", inputPath,
            filters,
            outputPath
        ]
        convertTask.standardInput = FileHandle.nullDevice
        convertTask.launch()
        convertTask.waitUntilExit()
    }
}
```

the `ffmpegFilters` variable array is defined in another function:

```
func conversionSelection() {
    if inputFileUrl != nil {
        let conversionChoice = conversionOptionsPopup.indexOfSelectedItem
        switch conversionChoice {
            case 1 :
                outputExtension = ".mp3"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c:a libmp3lame", "-ac 1", "-ar 22050", "-q:a 9"]
            case 2 :
                outputExtension = ".mp3"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c:a libmp3lame", "-ac 2", "-ar 44100", "-q:a 5"]
            case 3 :
                outputExtension = ".mp3"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c:a libmp3lame", "-ac 1", "-ar 22050", "-b:a 32k"]
            case 4:
                outputExtension = ".flac"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c:a flac"]
            default :
                outputExtension = ".m4b"
                ffmpegFilters = ["-c copy"]
        }
    }
}
```

So my array of strings is being used as an item in another array of strings.
When I do this, my @IBAction at the top there gives me an error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type
>   'String'

And I'm not sure how to fix that. It's really important I get the formatting of these ffmpeg arguments correct, because right now my project is stuck due to ffmpeg not liking the arguments Swift is passing to it in this process, so I'm trying to make everything relating to the arguments as bullet-proof as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argument `filters` is of type `String` in the below method declaration,

```
func ffmpegConvert(inputPath: String, filters: String, outputPath: String)
```

but in the IBAction method `startConversionClicked`, you are passing an `array` of `String`(`[String]`) instead of `String` which is wrong.

Just to silence the compiler, try this inside `startConversionClicked`,

```
ffmpegConvert(inputPath: inputFilePath, filters: ffmpegFilters.joined(), outputPath: "outputFilePath")
```

Here `ffmpegFilters.joined()` will return a `String`, same type that method argument `filters` expects.

Comment: Perfect that was exactly what I was missing. Thank you!